# How to customize the value of x & y-axis labels in kibana

Tags: angularjs, kibana, kibana-4, kibana-3

How to customize the labels in x and y axis in Kibana . Currently getting only the key name that given in the option. is there any way to customize it in angular js? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This will be part of kibana 4.5 and 5.0.  See [the issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2386).